# Certificate for computation of ideal class group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory

Is there a known way of producing a certificate that can be used to more quickly verify that an ideal class group of a number field was computed correctly? More formally, I would like to know if there's a pair of algorithms (whose correctness is proven independent of conjectures such as GRH) with the following properties:

- Algorithm A takes as input a number field $K$, and outputs the class group $\operatorname{Cl}(K)$, plus some additional data $D$.
- Algorithm B takes as input a number field $K$ and additional data $D$ in the same format produced by algorithm A, and outputs the class group $\operatorname{Cl}(K)$ if $D$ is a valid certificate for $K$ as produced by algorithm A. Moreover, algorithm B should be asymptotically faster than any known unconditional algorithm for the computation of class groups when given a valid certificate (but must not silently give incorrect output when given an *invalid* certificate, meaning the algorithm can't "cheat" by just trusting the certificate without verifying).

Ideally, algorithm A should have similar runtime to standard unconditional algorithms for computing the class group (that is, producing the certificate shouldn't slow things down too much), and algorithm B should be at least as fast as computing the class group using Bach's bound (which is conditional on GRH), but I'd even be curious to know if such a certificate can give *any* significant improvement in runtime.

(For context, I'm working on a computational problem where correctness of the result depends on the computation of a class group; in the range of data I'm focusing on, it's slow but still feasible to compute the class groups unconditionally, so it'd be nice if it were possible to produce a certificate that would allow other people to verify that the class group was computed correctly without having to do the whole long computation themselves.)

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect Algorithm B to do when given an incorrect certificate? Should it say that the certificate is incorrect, or should it say always do one of the following: (i) compute the correct class group anyway or (ii) say that the certificate is incorrect?

Comment: A naive way: state of the art methods follow the index calculus approach. They find elements of $K$ that generate an ideal that factors over prime ideals with bounded norm. Finding these elements is the hard part. Once enough of these are known, the structure of the class group comes from linear algebra (HNF). So you could just save these elements and call it the certificate (but it might be expensive in terms of memory).

Comment: It may be informative to consider the case in which the class group is trivial. What would the certificate (have to) look like then? One brute force way to do it would be have the certificate give a principal generator for each prime ideal of norm less than the Minkowski bound. Of course, this doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a better way in this case?

Comment: I don't particularly care what Algorithm B does when given an incorrect certificate, as long as it doesn't silently give incorrect output. It could say the certificate is incorrect, it could compute the class group anyway, or it could even get stuck in an infinite loop—all of these I'd consider acceptable, though obviously the last option isn't preferable. The properties of Algorithm B that I care about are that (1) if it outputs a class group, then that output is guaranteed to be correct, and (2) if given a valid certificate, it outputs a class group relatively quickly.

Comment: And yes, I suppose one could just give a principal generator for each of a whole long list of prime ideals up to the Minkowski bound, but that does indeed seem very space-inefficient, so I was hoping for something better (I would guess that such a method might not even give much of a speedup in practice, since you'd still have to be computing something for each prime ideal up to the Minkowski bound, even if it's a slightly faster computation for each prime).

Comment: I wonder if one could just save the output of pari's bnfinit and then use bnfcertify. But I don't really know what the latter does. - Somehow the list of generators of the class group and the fundamental unit together with the class number formula should be a good check to start with.

Comment: Chris: I agree that's a start, but I suppose the problem is that it could be that the claimed class group is in fact too small and that the claimed regulator is too large, but the class number formula won't detect this as the two errors could cancel out.

Comment: In special cases, there are some nice tricks, e.g. as described here https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1094

Comment: @HenriJohnston that won't be an issue if you're careful about what information you use for verification. If you have a set of generators of ideals which factor over the prime ideals of bounded norm, their exponents in this factorization will give a matrix called the relation matrix. It's HNF gives the structure of the class group and It's kernel will give a set of fundamental units whose regulator is the regulator of $K$. Then use the class number formula to verify these numbers are correct (using the approximation of the Dedekind zeta function of Buchmann and Williams).

Comment: Again though, this requires saving each of these generators. Asymptotically this might not be too memory efficient, but it definitely should not be an issue in practice.